# Posting a variable which is the "name" of form input

Tags: php, input

So I have the issue that I am trying to post a variable which is the name of a form input checkbox. However, this name is a variable. When I view page source it shows the name as what I want it to however when I have:

```
$files_name = $_POST['$file_name'];
```

Which works for the other elements that I have, it does not send the value that $file_name has. I assume it may have something to do with concatenating variable but I've looked up how it is that I'm supposed to do this but I can't work out how to do it or what to do.

---

I have a new kind of issue. This is because whenever I try to show the value of $file_name at any stage, for some reason it is blank EXCEPT when used in the name="$file_name" in the form, almost as though it loses its value.

Comment: Are you generating the html?  $_POST is a dictionary object with strings for the keys.   So when you use '$file_name' the key that is added is the string $filename

Comment: Where is `$file_name` coming from?  How are you setting that?

Comment: $file_name is equal to $file which is an array of file names for images which the user has uploaded and so what is displayed is user specfic.  I fear this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In single quotes, the variable is not interpreted, it's read literally as `'$file_name'`.  To have the value interpreted, use double quotes:

```
$files_name = $_POST["$file_name"];
```

You don't need quotes here at all, just use:

```
$files_name = $_POST[$file_name];
```

Comment: I've just found out that the issue is that $file_name does not seem to hold a value as when writing something like echo"$file_name"; it does not actually echo anything, nothing is shown in the page source either and yet in the original input which is in the form field, it shows as what I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

do it like that

```
     $files_name = $_POST[$file_name];
```